# Table generator for utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8, html-table

I need make a table whit UTF-8 characters, some like this: http://dev.networkerror.org/utf8/

I test **chr(int)**  but the documentation said that it's return ASCII characters, so I search some alternative or function but i don't fount nothing, can you help me? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For make the same that chr() but with utf-8:

```
iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', $int));
```